# What is the best practice to include scripts tag in react index.html in case of SSR(Server side rendering)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-redux-i18n

I have setted up my react app with server side rendering which loads create the HTML data at server side and returns the HTML data back to requested client. 
So in this case all loading the scripts tags/html data creating the components happens at the server side it self. To improve the performance of my page what is the best practice to include the script tag ?
Is it in the head tag or in body tag or after body tag. Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to keep the `scripts` in the bottom of the `body` tag. (And in the `Layout` page)

Comment: but wherever i keep it, it will takes it own time to process in server side and consumes time right ? Please explain me how it improves performance ?

Comment: It depends on the `scripts` (Libraries) you are using. Performance is not only depends in `scripts`. for further reference visit [Safari] (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/web-performance-tuning/1565923790/ch01s02.html) , [progress](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-server-side-development-performance-tips)